# PHP - preg_match for only numbers and single dash

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Let's say I only allow this kind of format `2015-2016` which contains number and only one dash. How can I do this with `preg_match`? I tried the following, but with no luck.

```
$a = '2015-2016';
if(!preg_match('/[^0-9\-]/i',$a)) {
    then return not valid data`
}
```

Comment: Just use `'/^\d+-\d+$/'` as a valid regex

Comment: i'm just a beginner with php, espcially with `preg_match` and `regex`, can you explain the meaning of `'/^\d+-\d+$/'`? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can the numbers be `12-12345` or just 4 digit numbers are supported?

Comment: actually it's a year started and ending, example is a school year, let's say from 2014 to 2015 in academic year it is written `2014-2015` i want to apply it with this format.

Comment: Then use Neel's answer.

Comment: Ok. thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
preg_match('/^\d{4}-\d{4}$/', $string);
```

`^` Start of the string

`\d{4}` match a digit [0-9] Exactly 4 times

`-` matches the character - literally

`\d{4}` match a digit [0-9] Exactly 4 times

`$` End of the string

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = '2015-2016';
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9 \-]+$/',$a)) {
 then return not valid data }
```

Try that.

Comment: Thank you! i tried the first answer which is `'/^\d+-\d+$/'` and i tried your answer, both are giving me the correct answer, now, which one is the  best to use? i only want to allow format like `academic year`.

Comment: The best answer (since you need to match 4-digit pairs) is Neel's.